# sort the fixed data table on the click of a header

Tags: fixed-data-table

I have a fixed data table which is rendered in the order of the API response. 
I want to sort the table on the click of an header primarily an 'id' in Ascending and Descending order

Is there a simple way to implement it from other than the example given in the docs

Comment: Hello Erick, could you please provide us some more information? What framework are you using, what have you tried so far? Creating detailed questions will ensure you get helpful answers!

Comment: @AndrewAdam I am using Reactjs and I have tried working with the code given on 
https://github.com/schrodinger/fixed-data-table-2/blob/master/examples/SortExample.js

I am not able to implement it properly.